# is_valid() not running after my form request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        date_added= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        price= models.FloatField(blank=True)
        zip_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        category= models.CharField(max_length=20 ,choices=category_choice, default=None)
        condition = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=condition_choices, default=None)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Views.py

```
def create_products(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'listtheproduct' in request.POST:
        print("RAN LIST")
        create= ProductForm()
        create.user = request.user
        create.price = request.POST['price']
        create.title = request.POST['title']
        create.description = request.POST['description-of-product']
        create.zip_code= request.POST['location-of-product']
        create.category = request.POST['category']
        create.condition = request.POST['condition']
        if create.is_valid():
            print("RAN")
            images = request.FILES.getlist('product-image')
            print(images)
        else:
            print("INVALID")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        create= ProductForm()
    return render(request,'product/product.html', {'create':create})
```

I am trying to get the inputs from my html file and put them into the views.py. I do not think it is working because when I check to see if "create.is_valid()" it ends up not running at all.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please copy *code fragments* in the question, not *images* of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to the form, without this data, the form is not bounded, and thus can not be validated:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'listtheproduct' in request.POST:
    create = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # …
```

Note that you should *not* assign the values to the form, so:

```
create.price = request.POST['price']
```

does not make much sense. The form will take the data from the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` and process it accordingly:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_products(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'listtheproduct' in request.POST:
        create= ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if create.is_valid():
            create.instance.user = request.user
            create.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        create= ProductForm()
    return render(request,'product/product.html', {'create':create})
```

In the model, you should make the `user` field non-editable:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.USER_AUTH_MODEL,
        editable=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: it still is printing invalid for me. Its not even going through the create.is_valid()

Comment: @olsisadiku: then `listtheproduct` is not in the `request.POST` data.

Comment: so i added another print statement to see if the listproduct is in request.POST, it said that it ran list. You can look at my views.py to see the new print statement i added after the first if.

Comment: @olsisadiku: exactly what does it say when you print `print(request.POST)`? Did you add the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the model form?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['4qDD1SJ3wOqTADKujsckjnKZLeIeZqW8rgoqFK0QqEIXoPepdqH8nrVq1v0vt3ij'], 'chooseFile': [''], 'title': ['qwdq1wd'], 'price': ['13123'], 'description-of-product': ['dwdqw'], 'category': ['auto-parts'],
 'condition': ['used-acceptable'], 'location-of-product': ['1231231'], 'listtheproduct': ['']}>
Invalid

Comment: @kixsmart: what if you create the modelform, and then check if it is `.is_valid()`?